# Time-window rolling sum in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, time-series, window-functions, rolling-computation

I'd like to know if it's possible to use window queries based on time in Postgresql.

The original data is in the first three columns (date, salesman, amount):

| date | salesman | amount | sum-3-rolling-days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | john | 10 | 10 |
| 2020-01-02 | john | 15 | 25 |
| 2020-01-03 | john | 8 | 33 |
| 2020-01-04 | john | 12 | 35 |
| 2020-01-05 | john | 11 | 31 |
| 2020-01-01 | daniel | 5 | 5 |
| 2020-01-02 | daniel | 6 | 11 |
| 2020-01-03 | daniel | 7 | 18 |
| 2020-01-04 | daniel | 8 | 21 |
| 2020-01-05 | daniel | 9 | 24 |

The fourth column represents the total amount by this salesman during the past three rolling days.

Pandas has built-in functions to do this, but I can't think of any way to do it in Postgresql using built-in `sum() over ()` syntax. The only way I was able to is using a convoluted mix of lateral joins and subqueries with conditions on time delta comparisons, which is inelegant to say the least.

Pandas' way (by memory, exact syntax might differ slightly) — cannot get any terser:

```py
df.groupby('salesman').rolling('3d').sum()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[demos:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=723b24c940fe59f9403dfc06dc24e1b9)

```
SELECT
    *,
    SUM(amount) OVER (
        PARTITION BY salesman                     -- 1
        ORDER BY "date"                           -- 2
        ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW  -- 3
    )
FROM mytable
```

1. Build groups/partitions by the `salesman`. So, the following will only done *within* theses partitions
2. Order them by the `date` column
3. Sum only those records which are between 2 date fore the current one and the current one. This is the rolling part

---

If you are using Postgres **11** or later, you can define the window even more precisely using `RANGE` with date intervals instead of counting `ROWS`:

```
SELECT
    *,
    SUM(amount) OVER (
        PARTITION BY salesman                    
        ORDER BY "date"                          
        RANGE BETWEEN interval '2 days' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    )
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CTE](https://popsql.com/learn-sql/postgresql/how-to-calculate-cumulative-sum-running-total-in-postgresql) (common table expression).
Try with

```
with data as (
select
  date,
  salesman,
  amount
from
  foo
group by
  date,
  salesman
order by
  date,
  salesman,
)

select
  *,
  sum(amount) over (
    partition by salesman order by date,
    salesman rows between unbounded preceding and current row
  ) as rolling
from data;
```