# Calculating moving sum (or SUM OVER) for the last X months, but with irregular number of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to do a window function (like the SUM() OVER() function), but there are two catches:

1. I want to consider the last 3 months on my moving sum, but the number of rows are not consistent. Some months have 3 entries, others may have 2, 4, 5, etc;
2. There is also a "group" column, and the moving sum should sum only the amounts of the same group.

In summary, a have a table that has the following structure:

| id | date | group | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01 | group A | 1100 |
| 2 | 2022-01 | group D | 2500 |
| 3 | 2022-02 | group A | 3000 |
| 4 | 2022-02 | group B | 1000 |
| 5 | 2022-02 | group C | 2500 |
| 6 | 2022-03 | group A | 2000 |
| 7 | 2022-04 | group C | 1000 |
| 8 | 2022-05 | group A | 1500 |
| 9 | 2022-05 | group D | 2000 |
| 10 | 2022-06 | group B | 1000 |

So, I  want to add a moving sum column, containing the sum the amount for each group for the last 3 months. The sum should not reset every 3 months, but should consider only the previous values from the 3 months prior, and of the same group.

The end result should look like:

| id | date | group | amount | moving_sum_three_months |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01 | group A | 1100 | 1100 |
| 2 | 2022-01 | group D | 2500 | 2500 |
| 3 | 2022-02 | group A | 3000 | 4100 |
| 4 | 2022-02 | group B | 1000 | 1000 |
| 5 | 2022-02 | group C | 2500 | 2500 |
| 6 | 2022-03 | group A | 2000 | 6100 |
| 7 | 2022-04 | group C | 1000 | 3500 |
| 8 | 2022-05 | group A | 1500 | 3500 |
| 9 | 2022-05 | group D | 2000 | 2000 |
| 10 | 2022-06 | group B | 1200 | 1200 |

The best example to see how the sum work in this example is line 8.

- It considers only lines 8 and 6 for the sum, because they are the only one that meet the criteria;
- Line 1 and 3 do not meet the criteria, because they are more than 3 months old from line 8 date;
- All the other lines are not from group A, so they are also excluded from the sum.

Any ideias? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: This is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66117160/time-window-rolling-sum-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUM()` as a window function partitioning the window by `group` in `RANGE` mode. Set the frame to go back 3 months prior the current record using `INTERVAL '3 months'`, e.g.

```
SELECT *, SUM(amount) OVER w AS moving_sum_three_months
FROM t
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY "group" ORDER BY "date"
             RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '3 months' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
ORDER BY id
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f09daf01ee8c8e92f5c662a2dee74de6)

Comment: Thanks! It was my first time posting at stackoverflow, and I was glad I got an answer so fast. I'll retribute answering some questions later. Thanks again!

Comment: I have a slight problem, though. RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL just works for postgres 10+. Otherwise, it gives the following error: "RANGE PRECEDING is only supported with UNBOUNDED". Any work arounds? Thanks!

Comment: @GSChacon which postgresql version are you using? :O

Comment: unfortunately I'ḿ using AWS Redshift, which uses postgresql 8.0, iirc.

Comment: @GSChacon jesus... this version is ancient! It's from 2005 and reached EOL in 2010(!). If you can, consider upgrading your system ASAP. You're missing all modern PostgreSQL features. Without window functions this would be much more complex and probably better solved in the application with a loop.